# ERROR: Could not build wheels for prophet, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: pip, facebook-prophet, pyproject.toml

I am trying to install prophet using
`pip install prophet`

installation goes well at first, but then fails with the following error

`ERROR: Failed building wheel for prophet Failed to build prophet ERROR: Could not build wheels for prophet, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects`

I use the following technologies:
Python 3.11.0
pip 22.3
windows 11

I suspect that the problem is somehow related to pyproject.toml but I don’t know what it is and how to install it, please tell me how to fix the error and install the prophet correctly

I tried to google a ready solution or advice, but I only found similar errors when installing other libraries using pip

in the answers, people recommend installing another library, but in different topics it is different

I want to understand what I need to install if an error occurs when installing the prophet

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I faced the same issue any by checking Prophet documentation found below command to install it and it worked for me.adding python -m at the begining the pip command helped.

python -m pip install prophet

Answer (score 3):

This error message suggests that there was a problem building the wheel for the Prophet package.

A wheel is a built package that contains the necessary files for a Python package, and it allows for faster installation. Building a wheel for a package involves compiling the package's code, which can sometimes fail due to various reasons.

Here are a few things you can try to solve the issue:

1. Try installing the package again with the `--no-binary :all:` option.
   This will force pip to build the package from the source, which may
   resolve any issues with the pre-built wheel. The command would look
   like this: `pip install prophet --no-binary :all:`
2. Make sure your system has all the necessary dependencies and build
   tools installed. Prophet requires a C++ compiler and Python
   development headers. Try using a virtual environment to install the
   package.
3. Make sure you have the latest version of pip and python installed.
4. Check if there is any issue related to it on GitHub

It could be helpful to check the Prophet's GitHub issues or documentation for any known compatibility issues or installation troubleshooting tips.

Comment: I have installed Microsoft C++ Build Tools
from https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/ru/visual-cpp-build-tools/ 

then I ran the command:

`pip install prophet --no-binary :all:`

and got the following error:

 `error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.34.31933\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\link.exe' failed with exit code 1104`

Answer (score 1):

Came here looking for way to combat the same error message, but for another module - AnnoyIndex. The latter while failing to install as well also pops out a message stating the following:

> Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with
> "Microsoft C++ Build Tools":
> https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

So I did exactly this:

1. followed a link,
2. downloaded Microsoft C++ Build Tools,
3. installed them
4. but also clicked on button near Microsoft C++ Build Tools to specify which exact components to install
5. and selected first one on the left called something along the lines of "Classic C++ apps development" (Sorry my version is not in English so I don't know exact name of this option).
6. Then rebooted my Win 10 PC and were able to install needed python module.

Comment: Very good insight for solving the problem. My computer was entirely clean of C++ stuff, doing this solved my problem when running `pip install TTS`.